# Git folder with files from two different branches

Tags: git, scripting

I'll just explain my scenario.

I have a folder managed with git containing a set of scripts which are automatically run. Each script have a corresponding filter file determining which files are to be run in response to different events. E.g.:

- a.script
- a.filter
- b.script
- b.filter

I have a branch containing some changes to the scripts, but we've decided for the time being to only roll them out for certain scenarios using the filters. So we'll end up with something like:

- a.script
- a_.script
- a.filter
- a_.filter
- b.script
- b_.script
- b.filter
- b_.filter

So what I need is to have the script files from the main branch, and the script files from the testing branch checked out together in one folder, with different names. I don't know when (or if) the testing branch will be merged into main, so I need to push changes to both branches. Is there any good way to solve this using git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already seem to have your additional or modified files in a separate branch (I’ll assume its name is `testing`); this branch should also contain the files from the `master` branch (because it was created from `master`, right?). Now create a third branch, e.g. `local` (or `unified` or whatever):

```
git checkout -b local master
```

Now merge your `testing` branch into it:

```
git merge testing
```

This should basically give you all modifications from all branches. Note that this branch is not for committing manually, you only merge either your `master` or your `testing` branch into it, commits always go to either of those branches, never to `local`!

This approach requires a bit of discipline because you should not commit to the `local` branch (unless you’re confident that you can `rebase` the commits to the `local` branch to the branch they should really go to). Also, it will look quite messed up in `gitk` because continued merges into a single branch tend to create some optical noise. This can be cleared up every now and then by repeating the two steps from above that will simply recreate the `local` branch — this is not a problem because all your changes have been committed to either `master` or `testing`.

Comment: The problem is I need `local` to contain two **separate** copies of files from `master` and `testing`. E.g. `foo.script` -> `foo.master.script` and `foo.testing.script`.

Comment: Can’t you just keep `foo.script` in master and `foo.testing.script` in `testing`? Or does the `testing` branch require changes in `foo.script`in addition to `foo.testing.script`?

Comment: For the automation system to work, all the scripts must be in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, but in your `testing` branch, do you *change* `foo.script`, or do you only *add* `foo.testing.script`?

Comment: `foo.testing.script` is based of `foo.script` and any changes to the latter should be pushed `foo.testing.script` as well.

Comment: That still does not tell me what `foo.testing.script` actually is: is it just a modified `foo.script`, or is it *an additional file?*

Comment: So, you want to store two separate files, but changes in `master`’s `foo.script` should automatically be reflected by `testing`’s `foo.testing.script`? I’m afraid the only solution for this scenario that I can think of involves a post-commit hook or some similar mechanism.

Comment: Okay, I was afraid of something like that. Time to start writing scripts. :/

Comment: Yes. Git’s purpose is storing your files, not modifying them. :)